# How do i re-instate the files from an old patch?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installshield

I have a basic MSI project in installsheild 2012. I want to be able to install a patch (major upgrade) which backs up the current configuration files when it is installed in way so that when I remove the patch that the old configuration files are re-instated. At the moment when I update these files are deleted.

I am self taught so I may not be following the best practises

I have looked everywhere but I cannot find an example, I might not be looking for the correct words that relate to this process

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be handled manually by copying the installed file to location, and once you do the upgrade copy back the file to the INSTALLDIR. I got to know from the below link, hope that helps you.

http://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-108435.html

-Anand

Comment: Hi Anand. I also came across that post but it's not really what I'm looking for. I have seen in other installations that when a patch is removed from add or remove programs it re-instates the files from the previous patch in the INSTALLDIR and then gives you the option to remove the other patches. So you can in effect with this process roll back your application through the versions on the clients machine.

Comment: Hi Cawston, I created a sample project and i added two CAs, one is to copy the file before install and place it in a temp folder, then the other to copy back after installation. I tried a major upgrade and it went thru fine.

Comment: Hi Anand, Thanks you for your help with this. are they standard Custom Actions that i can find within installshield 2012 or will i need to write them in installscript? Thanks again

Comment: Hi Cawston, You should write it thru installscript, or if you are familiar with any other script you can write in it and cab call it.. There is no standard CA's.